# alphanumeric sorting with php and preg_match

Tags: php

I have an array called $itemArray[] that contains a set of strings, such as:

```
myItem_1,
myItem_2,
myItem_3,
myItem_4,
anotherName_1,
anotherName_2,
anotherName_3,
anotherName_4
```

I also have the following code that goes through the array and filters out the ones that contain 'myItem'. 
The loop works, however, it returns results in varied order. Is there a way to sort the result of the array so 
that it lists them alphanumerically?

```
foreach($itemArray as $item) {
  if (preg_match('/myItem/',$item))
    echo '$item';
}
```

I don't have much experience with php and would definitely appreciate the help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP supports lots of ways to sort arrays, see how they work [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). You could run it as `asort($itemArray)`.

The right way to solve this is by sorting the array prior to outputting it. Something along the lines of:

```
asort($itemArray);
foreach($itemArray as $item) {
  if (preg_match('/myItem/',$item))
    array[index++] = $item;
}
```

Comment: link only answers are nor encouraged.

Comment: More detail was on the way :)